# JAVA: comparing a String with a SubString

Tags: java, string, loops, substring

So here's what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to make a code that does the following from 2 given Strings: a `target` and a `source`.

```
//  Determines whether the string TARGET occurs as a substring of string SOURCE where "gaps" are allowed between characters of target.`
//  That is, the characters in TARGET occur in SOURCE in their given order but do not have to be adjacent.`
//  (Pictured another way, this method returns true if TARGET could be obtained from SOURCE by removing some of the letters of SOURCE.)`
//  This method is case sensitive. For example,`
//  containsWithGaps("hamburgers", "mug") returns true`
//  containsWithGaps("hamburgers", "burrs") returns true`
//  containsWithGaps("hamburgers", "hamburgers") returns true`
//  containsWithGaps("hamburgers", "gum") returns false`
//  containsWithGaps("hamburgers", "hamm") returns false`
//  containsWithGaps("hamburgers", "") returns true`
//  Parameters:`
//  SOURCE - the given string in which to find the target characters`
//  TARGET - the characters to be found`

//  Returns:`
//  true if the characters in TARGET can be found as a subsequence in SOURCE, false otherwise`
```

And here's the code I've written. It seems to be overly complicated for what I believe shouldn't be a difficult task, but no matter what, I still keep getting errors and it won't work if given a SOURCE string `hamburgers` with a TARGET string `burr`:

```
    public static boolean substringWithGaps(String source, String target) {

    boolean substring = false;
    int[] target_index;
    target_index = new int [target.length()];

    if (target.length() > source.length()) {
        substring = false;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < target.length(); i++) {
            if (source.contains("" + target.charAt(i))) {           
                target_index[i] = target.indexOf(i);
                i++;
            }
            else {
                target_index[i] = target.indexOf(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < target_index.length; i++) {
            if (target_index[i] == -1) {
                substring = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (target_index[i] >= target_index[i+1]) {
                substring = false;
                break;
            }
            else {
                substring = true;
            }
        if (target_index.length != target.length()) {
            substring = false;
            }
        }   
    }
    return substring;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Pseaudocode: `String foo = source.replace(/\s+/, "", g); if (-1 != foo.indexOf(target) { hooray() }`

Comment: Just this `source.contains(target)`, in Java would work fine.

Comment: @Jorge Campos No, that will not satisfy the requirements - it will return true only if the target is exactly in the source. The requirement is that there can be intervening letters,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be pretty simple:

```
public static boolean substringWithGaps(String source, String target) {
    int targetIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
        if (source.charAt(i) == target.charAt(targetIndex)) {
            targetIndex = targetIndex + 1;
            if (targetIndex == target.length()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

We keep an index of the next letter we need to find within `target`. Then we loop over `source` looking for that letter, and when we find it we move the index within `target` forward one. If the index of `target` ever equals the length of `target`, that means we found all of the characters we needed. If we loop over all of source without finding all of `target`, we return false.

Comment: `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when target=""

Comment: Yea but that's what I don't seem to understand. take `source = "hamburger"` and `target = "burr"` On line 4 of your code, `       if (source.charAt(i) == target.charAt(targetIndex)) {` the targetIndex would stay at 0 until the loop iterated over `b` in `hamburger`, whose index# is 3, but targetIndex should still be at 0, so they would never equal.

Comment: @saka1029 I added in `if (target == ""){return true; }` to the top and it seems to work fine after that

Comment: Omg I'm an idiot. Okay I understand it now,  hahathanks!

Comment: @Muldawg2020 You ask why `targetIndex` stays at 0 in this code. `targetIndex` refers to the index of the string `target`. So the value of `targetIndex` SHOULD be 0 when searching for "b", while the index of `source` is allowed to move forward. Download the code and run it yourself if you don't think it works. I already tested it and got correct results.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do it.

```
public static boolean containsWithGaps(String a, String b){
    if(b.length() > a.length())
    {
      return false;
    }
    char[] targetChars = new char[b.length()];
    b.getChars(0,b.length(),targetChars, 0);
    int pos = 0;
    for(char myChar : targetChars)
    {
      pos = a.indexOf(myChar, pos);
      if(pos == -1)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight optimization in that it returns as soon as a character could not be matched (and doesn't crash if target is zero length)

```
public static boolean substringWithGaps(String source, String target) {
    for (int i = 0, last = -1; i < target.length(); i++) {
        if (-1 == (last = source.indexOf(target.charAt(i), last + 1)))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```